# php json object couldn't convert to string

Tags: php, json

I have this piece of PHP code which should accept a number sent from an Android app and search the equivalent to that number in the database (in the other field) and send the result to the Android app.

But I get this error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in  D:\xampp\htdocs\ \b.php

in this line:

```
mysql_query(" select  stock_account from  Stock where  phone_id=   (string)$data ")
```

This is the complete code:

```
if( isset($_POST["json"]) )
{
    $data = json_decode($_POST["json"]);

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

    $datatwo = mysql_query(" select  stock_account from  Stock where   id=   (string)$data ") or die(mysql_error()) ;  

    echo $datatwo;
}
```

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['json'] ?

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @ChrisBanks  the value of $_POST['json']  is the sent number from the android

Comment: what is the raw value? `var_dump($_POST['json'])` for us, or `var_dump($data)` for us

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer using the checkbox if it resolves your question, or optionally up vote an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that json_decode generates an object.
The second thing you want to is a value from the `$data` variable so we use `$data->id` to get the id from the JSON.  I'm casting it to an integer like this `$id = (int)$data->id;` and storing it in a new variable.  Now in the query you can pass the `$id` variable to fetch your row.

If you want a different value off your `$data` variable you will need to change `$data->id` to something else.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["json"])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST["json"]);

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

    $id = (int)$data->id;
    $datatwo = mysql_query("SELECT stock_account FROM Stock WHERE phone_id =$id") or die(mysql_error()) ;  

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($datatwo);
    echo $row['stock_account'];
}
```

Read more here: http://php.net/json_decode

> json_decode — Decodes a JSON string
>
> **Usage**: *mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )*

Comment: I get Resource id #6

Comment: Okay, now change `echo $datatwo` to this `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($datatwo); echo $row['stock_account'];` -- I updated my post with how it should look like

Comment: `Resource id #6` presents that MySQL has found a result set